# Get different results every time when call google places API based on lat long and radius

Tags: api, google-maps, google-places-api

I'm getting different results every time when I call google places API. I'm using **https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=1500&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY** API and put location lat & long & radius dynamically and call multiple times back to back. So I get different output every time. It gives me Zero results or 2-3 places on same API.
Check below images.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting different results because Nearby Search responses may be missing a few results occasionally; this is intended behavior for the API due to the distributed and constantly evolving nature of Google Maps.

Check out this issue reported in Google's Issue Tracker for reference https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119250563

Hope this helps!

Comment: If I change different keyword then I will get different result. I know that but If I use same keyword then it will give different result after some time check above images in keyword landmarks.

Comment: Oh I see, sorry. This query https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=100&keyword=Landmarks&key=MY_KEY returns ZERO_RESULTS for me at all times. Can you share the full results you get?

Comment: Please check above images. I have added images of results.

Comment: Thanks! I'll modify my answer shortly.